# PHP Give an image width and height

Tags: php, html, image, echo, image-size

How to put there size, I want to display edge image in 400X400 format:

- height = 400
- width = 400

Please give the code size in 400X400, thanks.

Here is the code:

```
<?php   
    // Grab the data from our people table
    $sql = "select * from njerz";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))   {
        echo "<div class=\"picture\">";
        echo "<p>";

        // Note that we are building our src string using the filename from the database
        echo $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'] . "<br />";
        echo "<img src=\"images/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /><br ;
        echo "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I understood correctly:

```
echo "<img src=\"images/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" height=\"400\" width=\"400\" /><br />";
```

that's all you need if you want to set the dimensions

Comment: `height=\"400\" width=\"400\" />` Seriously? How do we know if it is in pixels? shouldn't you include `px`

Comment: Height and width attributes DON'T expect px on the end. They never have. They expect an integer which means pixels, or a percentage. However they are depreciated. Height and width CSS properties do expect px or %.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a style attribute `style="width:400px; height:400px;"`

```
echo '<img src="images/'. $row['filename'] .'" style="width:400px; height:400px;" alt="" /><br />';
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check my code

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("PATH_OF_THE_IMAGE/".$row['filename']);

echo "<img src=\"images/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" height=\"".$height."\" width=\"".$width."\" /><br />";
```